# OpenCV cmake options to turn off calls to libraries

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake

I am compiling OpenCV to be used on a NUC running Wind River Linux that is basically empty. I only need the static libraries, so I was wondering what options to include to keep it from calling to things like libavcodec and eigen.

I used this command, and make and make install went fine, but when I go to use it, it starts hunting for other libraries.

```
cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

I know I could go through and say "WITH_EIGEN=OFF" and so on, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I don't think there's supposed to be a space between `-D` and `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`. It should spell `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I tried again without a space and had no effect

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this question, I just made a shell script that searched for everything that the program calls and then copied it into the NUC. Ended up copying around 380 .so files over.